# history.push is not working after setState with useState

Tags: reactjs

I have a strange issue with react, I'm not sure if it is because of the setState of react hook or I'm building the navigation in the wrong way. Here is my code:

```
         //App.tsx
            function App() {
              const { user, setUser, isLoading, setUserContext, setIsLoading } = GetUser();
        
              if(isLoading)
               return (
                <div style={spinnerStyle}>
                 <ClipLoader color="red" loading={isLoading.valueOf()} size={150} />
                </div>
               )
               return (
                <div>
                 <BrowserRouter>
                 <UserContext.Provider value={{isLoading, user, setUser, setUserContext, setIsLoading}}>
                  <Switch>
                   <Route exact path="/">
                    <Login/>
                   </Route>
                   <AuthRoute exact path="/Dashboard" component={Dashboard}></AuthRoute>
                  </Switch>
                 </UserContext.Provider>
                 </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
      );
            }
    
        //Login.tsx
        const Login = () => {
          const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
          const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
          const {isLoading, setIsLoading} = useContext(UserContext);
          const {login} = UseAuth();
          const history = useHistory();
        
          const handleSubmit = async (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            e.preventDefault();
            
            await login({username: username, password: password});
            setIsLoading(false);
        
            //history.push("/Dashboard");    when this code was executed, it does not navigate to Dashboard view. If I commented the setIsLoading for true/false, it worked
          };
          return (
             //Login html tags
          )
       }；
    
   //User.tsx (Custom Hook)
    function GetUser() {
        const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser | null>(null);
        const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<Boolean>(true);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            const getUser = async () => {
                await httpClient().get<IUser>("Accounts/get-user-session")
                    .then(res => {
                        setUser(res.data);
                        setIsLoading(false)
                    }).catch(err => {
                        setIsLoading(false);
                        console.log(err.response)
                    })
            }
            getUser();
        }, []);

         return {
                  user, isLoading, setUser, setIsLoading
         }
      }
```

The history.push("/Dashboard") is suppose to navigate to the Dashboard after the preloader loading state was updated to false, but it was not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`setIsLoading(false)` won't change the `isLoading` state right away due to the asynchronous nature of `setIsLoading` function. Therefore, you can use `useEffect` to track on `isLoading` state and then invoke `history.push("/Dashboard")` as follows.

But initially, `isLoading` can be `false`. Therefore, it's better to manage another state (`isNavigate` as in the below code) which is used to set true when you execute `handleSubmit` function and then set it false once the `useEffect` is executed with changed dependency `isNavigate`.

```
        //Login.tsx
        const Login = () => {
          const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
          const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
          const {isLoading, setIsLoading} = useContext(UserContext);
          const {isNavigate, setIsNavigate} = useState("");

          const {login} = UseAuth();
          const history = useHistory();
        
          const handleSubmit = async (e: React.SyntheticEvent) => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            e.preventDefault();
            
            await login({username: username, password: password});
            setIsNavigate(true);
            setIsLoading(false);  
          };

            useEffect(() => {
                if(isNavigate){
                    history.push("/Dashboard"); 
                    setIsNavigate(false);
                }
            }, [isNavigate]);
          return (
             //Login html tags
          )
       }；
```